# how to fix the replace method?

Tags: python, class

```
class type_name:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._fields = [x,y]
        self._mutable = False 

     def _replace(self,**kargs ):
        for key, value in kargs.iteritems():
            z = zip(key,value)
        for x in z:
            for y in self.field:
                if x[0] == y:
                    self.x = x[1]
                if x[0] == y:
                    self.y = x[1]
```

the _replace function, which takes **kargs as a parameter (keyword args). This allows the name kargs to be used in the method as a dict of parameter names and their matching argument values. The semantics of the _replace method depends on the value stored in the instance name self._mutable:

If True, the instance namess of the object it is called on are changed and the method returns None. So, if origin = Point(0,0) and we call origin._replace(y=5), then print(origin) would display as Point(x=0,y=5) because origin is mutated.

If False, it returns a new object of the same class, whose instance name's values are the same, except for those specified in kargs. So, if origin = Point(0,0) and we call new_origin = origin._replace(y=5), then print(origin,new_origin) would display as Point(x=0,y=0) Point(x=0,y=5) because origin is not mutated

I am not sure why my replace function does not work, can someone tell me how to fix it?

I added the bsc.txt to help to understand:

```
c-->t1 = Triple1(1,2,3)
c-->t2 = Triple2(1,2,3)
c-->t3 = Triple3(1,2,3)
# Test replace (not mutable)
==-->t1._replace(a=2)-->Triple1(2,2,3)
==-->t1._replace(a=2,c=2)-->Triple1(2,2,2)
^-->t1._replace(a=2,c=2,d=2)-->TypeError
==-->t1-->Triple1(a=1,b=2,c=3)
# Test _replace (mutable)
c-->Triple1 = pnt('Triple1', 'a b c',mutable=True)
c-->t1 = Triple1(1,2,3)
e-->t1._replace(a=2,c=2)-->None
==-->t1-->Triple1(a=2,b=2,c=2)
```

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you're trying to do but it sounds like you need `if self.is_mutable`, `setattr`, and to make a copy of the object..

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is much cleaner api for this kind of tasks. Use `getattr` and `setattr` for this. Firstly you need to fix `_fields` param. it should contain names not values.

```
class type_name:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._fields = ['x', 'y']
        self._mutable = False 

    def _replace(self, **kwargs):
        if self._mutable:
            for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
                setattr(self, key, value)
        else:
            for field in self._fields:
                if field not in kwargs:
                    kwargs[field] = getattr(self, field)
            return self.__class__(**kwargs)
```